# Slim PHP and Server Sent Events (SSE)

Tags: php, slim, server-sent-events

See [here](http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/questions/9028-how-to-implement-server-sent-events-sse-with-slim-3) for background:

With Slim how do I send multiple responses to the same request without exiting the application?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Slim Api version 2 and I added server sent events to my existing api this way:

In index.php:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

// other code
....

// this is the route I want to use for the event stream
$app->get( '/psoback/eventstream',
           function() use ($app)
           {
                require_once('event.php');
                $app->eventstream = new ServerSentEventHandler(); 
           }
         );

// here goes the rest of my api definitions
...

$app->run();

if(isset($app->eventstream))
{
   $app->eventstream->Run();
}
```

event.php looks like this: 
( example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events )

```
<?php
class ServerSentEventHandler
{
    function __construct()
    {

    }

    function Run()
    {
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        $counter = rand(1, 10);
        while (1) 
        {
          // Every second, sent a "ping" event.

          echo "event: ping\n";
          $curDate = date(DATE_ISO8601);
          echo 'data: {"time": "' . $curDate . '"}';
          echo "\n\n";

          // Send a simple message at random intervals.

          $counter--;

          if (!$counter) 
          {
            echo 'data: This is a message at time ' . $curDate . "\n\n";
            $counter = rand(1, 10);
          }

          ob_end_flush();
          flush();
          sleep(1);
        }
    }
};
?>
```